# How to understand this slice()?

Tags: javascript

What does the following slice do in javascript?

```
str.slice(0, num > 3 ? num - 3 : num)
```

Comment: this will cause error since num is undefined.  Want to learn about slice? then start from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: If only there was a website where you could search for something like 'Javascript Slice'....

Comment: To expand your knowledge for the slice which is not only in string.prototype but also it has in array.prototype. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's string [`slice(begin, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string. It takes 2 arguments, where to begin and where to end.

In your example, the 2nd argument is a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). A ternary is shorthand for an if/else clause.

```
condition ? true : false;
```

In your case, the ternary is

```
num > 3 ? num - 3 : num
```

This means if `num` is greater than 3, return `num - 3`, otherwise just return `num`.

Comment: @JingCheng if this answered your question, be sure to mark it correct.